# how to convert a c# Datetime Object to json on razor pages for client side manipulation

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to convert a stored datetime object from database to Json object on the razor view page so as to manipulate it and compute time elapsed for a list of users in real time. I'm not sure how to do this. Please help!

I figured it would be best to convert it on the view page but I'm not sure if that is the best solution

```
@model List<WebApplication1.Models.Attendance>

<html>
<body>
    @foreach (var attendance in Model)
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th> Name </th>
                <th> Time Elapsed </th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td> @attendance.ApplicationUserId  </td>
                <td class="DateTimeObject" data-date="@attendance.DateAndTimeIn.ToString("u")"> @attendance.DateAndTimeIn </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    }


    <script type="text/javascript">



            var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

            const seconds = 1000;
            const minutes = seconds * 60;
            const hours = minutes * 60;
            const days = hours * 24;
            const years = days * 365;


            function myTimer() {

                let dateTimeValue = document.getElementsByClassName("DateTimeObject");

                for (i = 0; i < dateTimeValue.lenght; i++)

                {
                const startDateTime = new Date(dateTimeValue[i].dataset.date);
                const newDateTime = new Date();

                let elapsedMilliseconds = newDateTime - startDateTime;


                document.getElementsByClassName("DateTimeObject").innerHTML =
                        `${formatElapsedTime(elapsedMilliseconds, days)}:${formatElapsedTime(elapsedMilliseconds, hours, 24)}:${formatElapsedTime(elapsedMilliseconds, minutes, 60)}:${formatElapsedTime(elapsedMilliseconds, seconds, 60)}`;

                }


            }



            function formatElapsedTime(elapsedtime, timeunit, base) {
                let time = base ? (elapsedtime / timeunit) % base : elapsedtime / timeunit;
                time = Math.floor(time);
                time = time < 10 ? '0' + time : time;
                return time;
            }

        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to convert `@attendance.DateAndTimeIn` to a json object so I can use it with my javascript function and display the time elapsed instead of `@attendance.DateAndTimeIn`

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest way to do it is output your datetime to [universal datetime string](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#UniversalSortable) and then create a js `Date` instance from that string:

```
var dateString = '@Model.YourDate.ToString("u")';
var parsedDate = new Date(dateString);
```

See example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hY1ISw

**Update:**
You can put your date in the html attribute and later use it in your js code:

```
<td class="DateTimeObject" data-date="@attendance.DateAndTimeIn.ToString("u")">@attendance.DateAndTimeIn</td>

<script type="text/javascript">     
    const dateElements = document.getElementsByClassName('DateTimeObject');
    for(let i = 0; i < dateElements.length; i++){
        var dateString = dateElements[i].dataset.date;          
        var parsedDate = new Date(dateString);              
    }
</script>
```

Updated example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fhz8bP

Comment: I modified my javascript code to implement your solution but I don't know how to covert all the items in the list to javascript  string

Comment: @user8964654, I've update my solution to handle the values from the loop.

Comment: for some reason the same solution is not working for me and I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: @user8964654 line `document.getElementsByClassName("DateTimeObject").innerHTML` is not correct becuase getElementsByClassName return collection of elements, not the single one. Probably you need this: `dateTimeValue[i]..innerHTML = ...`

Answer (score 0):

If you add an ID to the table as well as having an common class on the `<td>` tag for the dateTime you could loop through all the rows in the tables such as this.

```
$('#//TableID tr').each(function() {
    var dateTimeValue = $(this).find(".//DateTimeClass").html();    
});
```

OR if the datetime is always gunna remain second in the table order, you could replace this line

```
var dateTimeValue = $(this).find(".//DateTimeClass").html();
```

with

```
var dateTimeValue = $(this).find("td").eq(1).html();
```

NOTE: Instead of .html(), you could also use .text()

Comment: I tried you solution but it gives me an error  ```"Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementByClassName' "```

Comment: @user8964654 That's not in my answer